# How to make a picker with custome values?

Tags: android, android-edittext, picker

I have made an Android application in that I want to put a value picker as shown in the image below. Can anyone help me how to make it? I want a picker with 4 values `"100","110","125","150"` and the selected value should be set in an `EditText`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest thing I know: [Android wheel](http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/)

Comment: the link is working. There are demo apps in the download section as well

Answer (score 0):

another solution is to define a numberpicker with values-> setDisplayedValues.
this maybe will help http://androidpp.wordpress.com/2013/11/07/numberpicker-als-valuepicker-mit-eigenen-werten/